# Forces when a ball rolls down an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation

I apologize if this seems trivial, but I am having some trouble understanding the solution to the following problem:

[image]

First off, there is a normal force that the plane exerts on the ball, and the component of the ball's weight that is parallel to the plane. But doesn't friction also act in the direction of the ball rolling? Since the ball rolls/rotates in the direction opposite to it's total motion, doesn't friction actually help the ball go down the incline? This is what I thought, and I figured that the total force parallel to the incline is the friction plus the parallel component of the ball's weight. So shouldn't the correct answer to the question be down and to the right?

Thanks

Comment: It's by no means trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question restricts our consideration to the force exerted **on** the plane **by** the ball.   There are only two components to this force:  (1) the normal force exerted on the plane by the ball perpendicular to the surface of the plane, and (2) the friction force exerted on the plane by the ball downward parallel to the plane.

When you add these two component forces, you do get **E** as the best representation of the total force, but the "Solution" is poorly written and confusing.   It's true that the friction force exerted on the ball by the plane (equal and opposite to the friction force exerted on the plane by the ball) must be less than the parallel force exerted by gravity on the ball, if the ball is accelerating, but those aren't forces exerted on the plane.